# Generate an array with common/uncommon elements in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array called `Sites`. Each element of the array has 3 objects:

- name
- presentData
- pastData

The `name` is formed by a single string element.

The `presentData` is a string containing numerical values for more data and it is present for all sites.

`pastData` contains same but there are sites which doesn't have data, it is only an empty array `[]`

My goal is to create an array which has the length of the initial array, having as values the `name` for the array which have also `pastData` and to be `null` or `""` for the ones that don't.

Having this input:

```
Sites = [
    {name: "name1",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: [423, 123, 53, 11, 6]
    },
    {name: "name2",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: [423, 123, 53, 11, 6]
    },
    {name: "name3",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: [423, 123, 53, 11, 6]
    },
    {name: "name4",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: []
    },
    {name: "name5",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: []
    },
    {name: "name6",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: [423, 123, 53, 11, 6]
    },  
];
```

Output should be: `["name1", "name2", "name3", null, null, "name6"]`

I tried it many ways but without success, I guess the closest one to the solution looks like this:

`Sites.filter(s => s.presentData.length).map(s => s.name).filter(s => s.pastData)`

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Put your code in example and people can improve upon it.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can give this a try:

```
Sites.filter(s => s.presentData.length).map(s => s.pastData.length ? s.name : null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly this is what you wanna:

```
var desiredArray = [];
Sites.forEach(function(element){
    if (element.pastData.length === 0) desiredArray.push(null);
    else desiredArray.push(element.name);
});
```

It basically iterates trough `Sites` and for each element (that's your obj with data) it's putting either a name or null in another array. Since data source is array, order of names is preserved.

I prefer this over filter + map since it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping the array should help solve the issue that you are facing. Why use filter for presentData when you are considering only the pastData array length.

```js
'use strict';
   
   let Sites = [
    {name: "name1",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: [423, 123, 53, 11, 6]
    },
    {name: "name2",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: [423, 123, 53, 11, 6]
    },
    {name: "name3",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: [423, 123, 53, 11, 6]
    },
    {name: "name4",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: []
    },
    {name: "name5",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: []
    },
    {name: "name6",
    presentData: [423, 23, 11, 54, 55],
    pastData: [423, 123, 53, 11, 6]
    },  
];

let result = Sites.map((a) => a.pastData.length < 1 ? a.name = null: a.name );
console.log(result);
```